# Correct capitalization when starting a sentence or headline with a parenthesized word

Tags: writing-style, capitalization, titles, headline-case, parentheses

What is the correct way of capitalizing the following sentence?

> (Most) people are good.

Should *people* also be capitalized? Or is it incorrect that *most* is capitalized?

Finally, does the same logic apply to titles and headlines, for instance the following title?

> (Almost) a Good Day

Comment: I would capitalize "People" -- the logic being that the first word of the **actual** title ought to be capitalized in **any** case; the parenthetical is secondary.  And, of course, the "A"  in the second case because the title is in Initial Capital style (all major words start with a capital letter).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Kris! Just to be clear, in the first example I'm asking about a regular sentence, not a title. In the second case I am indeed asking about a title. It is my understanding that "a" would be capitalized if the title was "A Good Day," but not capitalized if it was "Almost a Good Day." (see e.g. https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html). However, I don't quite understand how the parenthesis affects the capitalization.

Comment: As I said, the parenthetical is secondary. It doesn't influence the actual title.

Comment: Construct the sentence as if the parenthetical information didn't exist. The sentence is *People are good.*, with a capital *P*. What you do with the parenthetical information is up to you. Far more often than not this kind of information is superfluous anyway. If it were really important, it shouldn't be parenthetical in the first place. But I wouldn't put it at the start of the sentence because it would look strange to have two capitalized words next to each other. Instead, if I had to make the point in this sentence, I'd write *People (most of them) are good.*